# Which programming languages use this and how it works

Tags: c++, for-loop, language-agnostic

I found this for loop on the internet and since then I've been trying to find out which languages use it in order to find out how it works and convert this to C++

```
for m from 0 by 1 to n do 
 A[m] ← 1/(m+1)
 for j from m by -1 to 1 do
  A[j-1] ← j×(A[j-1] - A[j])
return A[0] (which is B_n)
```

Edit: I'm just curious, since I'm still learning programming and stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you found it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Algorithmic_description). This is not real programming language, but a pseudocode illustrating the algorithm.

Translation to C++ may look like this:

```
double SecondBernoulliNumber(int n)
{
    std::vector<double> A(n+1);
    for (int m = 0; m <= n; ++m)
    {
        A[m] = 1.0/(m+1);
        for (int j = m; j >= 1; --j)
        {
            A[j-1] = j * (A[j-1] - A[j]);
        }
    }
    return A[0];
}
```